# cannot group with eloquent with PostreSQL

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

Here's my Eloquent query:

```
$visits = Visit::orderBy('date', 'desc')->groupBy('user_id')->get(['date', 'user_id']);
```

But posgreSQL is refusing the query, telling me:

> SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR: column "visits.date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
>   LINE 1: select "date", "user_id" from "visits" group by...

the same stuff works on MySQL when I disable ONLY_FULLY_GROUP_BY

what can I do to make it work? It would be great if I didn't have to edit configs, just the code.

Comment: You can try turning off the strict mode in configs

Comment: Why are you grouping `users` by `user_id`? Isn't that the primary key?

Comment: no, it's not, I'll edit it so it's more clear

Comment: When there are multiple `visits` per `user_id`, which `date` do you want to get?

Comment: I can get even the random date (if it matches at least one visit of the user) The problem is with the error

Comment: What Laravel version are you using?

Comment: On this instance Laravel 5.2

Comment: Can there be multiple visits per `user_id` and `date` combination?

Comment: there shouldn't be, but there probably is some overlap, because there is 200+  devices that send out requests with this data

Answer (score 0):

This selects the latest `date` for each `user_id`:

```php
$sub = Visit::select('user_id', DB::raw('max("date") "date"'))->groupBy('user_id');
$sql = '(' . $sub->toSql() . ') as "sub"';
$visits = Visit::join(DB::raw($sql), function($join) {
    $join->on('visits.user_id', 'sub.user_id')
        ->on('visits.date', 'sub.date');
})->orderBy('visits.date', 'desc')->get(['visits.date', 'visits.user_id']);
```

If there are multiple visits for a `user_id` and `date` combination, the query returns all of them. Removing the duplicates is possible, but makes the query more complex.
It's easier to remove them afterwards:

```php
$visits = $visits->unique('user_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using postgre sql you could use `distinct on` user_id and order your date column to pick latest date per user_id, In laravel you could raw expression

```
$visits = Visit::select(DB::raw('distinct on (user_id)'), 'date')
          ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
          ->get();
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/BOHP99928)

Comment: I got error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on (user_id), `date` from `visits` order by `date` desc' at line 1 (SQL: select distinct on (user_id), `date` from `visits` order by `date` desc)

Comment: @TutuKaeen this query is valid for postgresql only , According to the error you are running this on Mysql. Please confirm which database vendor you are using Mysql or postgresql ?

Comment: yes, it was MySQL, I'm sorry, but PostreSQL also throws Error: Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: select distinct on (user_id), "date" from "visi...

Comment: The alias is missing: `distinct on (user_id) user_id`. And the demo query only works, because it orders by `user_id` AND `date`.